# Need validation with select option,

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, validation

my select option has value & text

```
<select id="roomType" class="roomType" name="roomType">
<option selected="selected" value="N/A">--Select--</option>
<option value="25">Deluxe</option>
<option value="26">Standard</option>
</select>
```

according to some validation it needs to selected value.

my js code

```
    //This is some validation method to make default 
    $(".roomOccupanice").each(function(){
            var $t = $(this),
            $select = $t.next().find('select');
            if ($t.text().toLowerCase() == roomOccOffline.toLowerCase()){   // this is met condition correctly
                $select[0].selectedIndex = $select.find('option').index($select.find('option[value^="'+roomTypeOffline+'"]')[0]); 

//roomTypeOffline = "Deluxe" i need to make this as selected 1 

}

        });
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly what you want to do? Do you want to check if the select field is selected with a value other than 'N/A'.

to check the selected value you can always do $select.val(); But I don't really know what you want to do.

Comment: @Navin validation works correctly, i need to set a option as Deluxe or Standard according to that, i am struck with set a text here instead of value $select.find('option[value^="'+roomTypeOffline+'"] roomTypeOffline variable value is Deluxe (for eg:)

Comment: @TeeJaay here roomTypeOffline = "Deluxe", i wanna make as selected if that condition match in js,

Answer (score 1):

As far i understood, you get a text "Deluxe" and with it you need to select the value "25".

If that's the case, i would suggest you to use Jquery selector [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

**JQuery**:

```
var roomTypeOffline = "Deluxe";
//get the option value that contains the text Deluxe
var selectValue = $("#roomType option:contains('"+roomTypeOffline+"')").val();
//Select that option
$("#roomType").val(selectValue);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bv7cz/)

Comment: yep i need this, i go with value, i don't know how to get that & i tried $select.find('option[text^="'+roomTypeOffline+'"] like that it didn't work